# Why multipart retrofit with "image/*" get bad request?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, multipartform-data, multipart

I want to post a Product with some details like name, desc, etc. and image too. But I got 400 bad request.

```
val namebody = name.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
val priceBody = price.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
val descriptionBody = description.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
val categoryBody = category.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
val locationBody = location.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())

val imageBody = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.name, imageBody)
```

```
@Multipart
    @POST("seller/product")
    suspend fun postProductSeller(
        @Header("access_token") access_token: String,
        @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
        @Part("description") description: RequestBody,
        @Part("base_price") base_price: RequestBody,
        @Part("category_ids") category_ids: RequestBody,
        @Part("location") location: RequestBody,
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    )
```

So after many tries, I have success to post image with retrofit but I have to change this line

```
val imageBody = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

to a spesific image format, example jpg, png.

```
val imageBody = imageFile.asRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

And anyone knows why is this happen? And how should I do if I want to upload any kind of image files? Thank you

Comment: "And anyone knows why is this happen?" -- talk to whoever maintains your Web service. "And how should I do if I want to upload any kind of image files?" -- supply the correct MIME type. You are the one who got the images. You know what MIME type they are.

Comment: @CommonsWare so the "image/*" not working is because the web service side? Because I search many tutorial use this and work

Comment: "so the "image/*" not working is because the web service side?" -- the Web service is what is returning 400 to you. The Web service therefore is the one that is deciding that it does not want a wildcard MIME type. "Because I search many tutorial use this and work" -- then perhaps you should talk to whoever maintains your Web service.

Comment: Did you checked file streaming when you called the API